# Safely Override Magento Core Resouce Method

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

I've had to change a method of Magento's Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category class. I've changed:

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
        $collection = $category->getCollection();
        /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
            ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
            ->joinUrlRewrite()
            ->load();
        return $collection;
}
```

To:

```
public function getChildrenCategories($category)
{
            $collection = $category->getCollection();
            /* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Category_Collection */
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('all_children')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('is_anchor')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addIdFilter($category->getChildren())
                ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
                ->joinUrlRewrite()
                ->load();
            return $collection;
}
```

Basically added `->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')` as I needed to get that attribute.

I'm stuck now on how to safely override this function. I've copied the entire class into `local > Mage > Catalog > Model > Resouce > Eav > Mysql4 > Category.php` but really I only need to override that one function.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You must override whole resource collection in your module. You can read how to override resource collection in this [forum thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/32486/).